# Error at the end of \listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I'm about to hand in a thesis that I'm writing using latex and overleaf. However, at the end of the list of figures, which I invoke by using the command `\listoffigures`, I get an extra sentence that says: `68figure.caption.52`, does anyone know how to remove this?

Comment: Hello, Dirac! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Without sharing any code nor a link to the overleaf project it is is very unlikely that somebody is able to help you ...

Answer (score 2):

\listoffigures should provide the list of figures. That looks like an incorrect caption for a figure. I developed a thesis template for my school that can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dublin-city-university-thesis-template/swhkfpjmcrfh) and uses list of figures and TOC.